# MS Access Query to get Distinct records from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like below:

```
ID  Demand_ID   Supply_ID   Supply_Skill    Supply_Designation  Supply_Location
1   D10         S10         Python          engineer            Mumbai
2   D10         S16         Python          engineer            Mumbai
3   D10         S2          Python          engineer            Mumbai
4   D10         S7          Python          engineer            Mumbai
5   D12         S12         Java            Manager             Bangalore
6   D1          S1          Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
7   D1          S11         Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
8   D1          S3          Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
9   D2          S10         Python          engineer            Mumbai
10  D2          S16         Python          engineer            Mumbai
11  D2          S2          Python          engineer            Mumbai
12  D2          S7          Python          engineer            Mumbai
13  D3          S1          Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
14  D3          S11         Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
15  D3          S3          Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
```

How do get a unique records like below:

```
ID  Demand_ID   Supply_ID   Supply_Skill    Supply_Designation  Supply_Location
1   D10         S10         Python          engineer            Mumbai
5   D12         S12         Java            Manager             Bangalore
6   D1          S1          Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
10  D2          S16         Python          engineer            Mumbai
14  D3          S11         Java            Senior engineer     Bangalore
```

Please tell me a logic to get unique records like above, and with the below condition like data from `Supply_ID` to `Supply_Location` should not be repeated for a `Demand_ID`.

Like in the above example `Demand_Id` `D10` and `D2` are having same set of next column records. If one of the column is matching for `D10` then it should not be repeated for `D2`. For `D2` it can pick any records from the corresponding columns except the record already picked from `D10`.

Comment: Why should D10 go before D2? Seems like you need some kind of script based solution here.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not exactly getting distinct records (because the original table has distinct records) but getting the first record for each `Demand_Id`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Supplies_And_Demands
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT MIN(ID)
                FROM Supplies_And_Demands
               GROUP BY Demand_Id)
```

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for the reply. based on your Query, Supply_ID, Supply_Skill, Supply_Designation and Supply_Location will be repeated.  for D10,  S10  will be fetched same will be from D2 record also. I need another records apart from S10 for D2.

Comment: Ah. I didn't quite understand the question. What you've got is an optimization problem, and those are difficult to express in SQL. It can be done (at least in some databases). See this craziness. https://technology.amis.nl/2009/10/13/oracle-rdbms-11gr2-solving-a-sudoku-using-recursive-subquery-factoring/